# Is it permissible for men to wear women's undewear because they are more comfortable and have better colors?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, men, clothing

I've asked this question before, and I want to reiterate it to clear up some misconceptions. Please do not immediately downvote this post (most people do), and read it in full before making any judgment.

From my last question and in my research, I have found that the judgment of wearing clothes is dependent on custom. This means that if a majority of men were to wear women's underwear, it would be fully lawful in Islam to wear them as it would not be considered imitation of the other gender.

**First question, is my conclusion above true? If not, why?**

Men have started to wear women's underwear, purely for their soft fabric and fun colors. There are several websites that promote men to do this, and several social media sites prove that it is becoming slowly becoming common for men to wear women's underwear.

I personally enjoy wearing them simply because they are extremely comfortable and have 10 times better colors than men's underwear. It's not clothing that is apparent outward, since it is just underwear. For the context of this question, I am referring to only panties. They do cover me just as well as men's underwear do.

I would like to clear up any misconceptions I have. If you do downvote this question as everyone automatically does, please comment your reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

walecum assalam brother.

This issue is delicate, and has doubt in it that how and to which level ,a man may imitate a woman,only then it is prohibited? actually there is no fine line to clear this point.

There is crystal clear hadith about this point:

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him)
>   said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) cursed the man who wears women’s clothing and the woman who wears
>   men’s clothing. Narrated by Abu Dawood (4098) and classed as saheeh by
>   al-Nawawi in al-Majmoo’ (4/469) and by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi
>   Dawood.

It pretty much clears that its better to avoid wearing their clothes.but still if you want to go further,that what to do as you are doubtful,then here is hadith for it.

> "The lawful is clear and the unlawful is clear, and between them are
>   doubtful matters about which many people do not know. **Thus he who
>   avoids doubtful matters clears himself in regard to his religion and
>   his honour**, but he who falls into doubtful matters [eventually]
>   falls into that which is unlawful, like the shepherd who pastures
>   around a sanctuary, all but grazing therein. Truly every king has a
>   sanctuary, and truly Allah’s sanctuary is His prohibitions. Truly in
>   the body there is a morsel of flesh, which, if it be whole, all the
>   body is whole, and which, if it is diseased, all of [the body] is
>   diseased. Truly, it is the heart.”

honestly speaking, you MUST avoid it (or you might be doing a sin) and logically too, even if there is that much need for it,then you can buy or preare some for you by some specialist,that is only for you.

you can read scholarly vie point here: http://islamqa.info/en/81994

And Allah knows the best

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is very clear, but I just want to understand one misconception I have. There are manufacturers selling male underwear that are similar to women's panties. These are ALL accepted by the majority as for men, as they are marketed as such. Would these be permissible to wear?

Comment: And as you mentioned that I could get some prepared by a specialist, if I simply told them to make a panty for me for men, that would be permissible? I understand its a very delicate issue, and I understand that it is best to avoid this. However, it is very hard for me to stop this as I have been wearing womens panties for quite a while. If there is any reasoning that wearing them is OK, I would love to keep wearing them since they are super comfortable and my wife loves them. If not, I will have to stop which will be a slow and tough road for me.

Comment: The biggest question in this issue, is what determines what is women's underwear and what is men's underwear. The first time I asked this question, the conclusion was that whatever is the custom of where the person is living is the law. Based on this, if women's panties are commonly worn by men in the United States, wouldn't this justify men to wear them?

Comment: Sorry, @user8189, the conclusion which you drew is totally wrong. But yeah sure, you can ask the garment manufacturers to prepare a super soft underwear with lots of comfort especially for men. That is highly preferable.

Comment: Understood. Looks like its time to stop.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not Islam I have been studying the Quran and have only this advice. Women's underwear is indeed made for women. Along with men's underwear for men. That being said...  There are some websites out there that make underwear out of those same fabrics and fun colors for men also known as manties. Perhaps since they are made for men this would be acceptable to Allah? Please forgive me if I have offended anyone in anyway. I do hope this information is helpful.

Comment: Searching for "manties" gave me the impression that it's a fetish thing.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, if more men were to wear panties then it wouldn't actually be a gender issue anymore.

So if gender barriers can actually be broken, is there actually any point in taking the verse about imitating genders very seriously? It's such a vague verse from a hadith. There's really no real way to differentiate between genders, except through modern traditions that people themselves develop. Traditions that can be easily broken and changed. I asked sort of a similar question also.

Also I realized this question is from 2015... oh well.

When men do culturally women things, like in terms of dress and manner, it becomes such a huge issue - when in reality it's not even an issue. Same goes for women to men. I think Orthodox Muslims take that issue to a whole 'nother level. Men and women should be able to freely dress however they want, as I see nothing wrong with breaking gender norms.

To go as far as to bully a man or women for doing culturally different things, or even tell them they're not true Muslims, or kick them out, or shun them... It's pretty extreme. It's one of those verses that are vague and, in my opinion, taken too literally and seriously by people. The interpretations of the verse are harmful and cause conflict.

The verse itself is okay, because it establishes that there are two genders -- not always -- but who the heck *defines* what it means to be culturally a man or a woman? The people do, so that's just unfair.

So yes, I say it's okay for men to wear panties. But as a woman who wears panties, I don't understand why anyone would want to... they're very uncomfortable in my opinion.

And aren't hadiths like super questionable and unreliable? They aren't the Quran, they're just alleged sayings/observations of Prophet Muhammed's life. You can read the hadiths and take what you will from it, but I advise people to focus more on following the Quran instead (since that's actually the WORD of God muahaha). But even then, there are still many vague things and in the end you have to ask for yourself: Does what I do cause any real harm towards other people and be morally wrong in general? In this case the answer's just no.

Answer (score -2):

I really don't think it is wise to wear women's underwear, unless you are a woman. It is the thin end of the wedge. One step closer to being gay. Next thing you know you'll be using a little lipstick and mascara and maybe you think a ribbon would look nice around that ponytail. Before you know it you're walking with a sway and wearing nail polish. Only one way this can end. Don't do it, it is weird and a bit pervy. This is an Aussie man's advice anyway. I also cannot imagine how I could wear women's panties. There'd be bits sticking out. Maybe if one can fit inside a pair of frilly panties made for women who have no protuberances, then the only issue is misidentifying one's own gender?  (Sorry, Aussies have an irreverent sense of humour.)

Answer (score -2):

HUKUM PRIA PAKAI CELANA DALAM WANITA.